# можно ли упростить проверку первого бита любой переменной?

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Основной вопрос можно ли обойтись без первого if в процедуре checkFirstBit(int size_arg, ...)
Второй вопрос можно ли сделать еще проще?
Третий вопрос все ли по феншую с данным решением? начиная от смысловой части решения, заканчивая оформлением?
заранее спасибо за конструктивную критику и предложения.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void checkFirstBit(int size_arg, ...)
// процедура проверяет первый бит переменной на равенство "1" и выводит переменную, если TRUE'''
{
    int bit_num = 8; // для побитового вывода переменной 
    int *ptr = &size_arg + 1; // адрес переданной переменной
    int binary_cond; 
// можно ли обойтись без данного if?
    if (size_arg == 1) binary_cond = 0x80;
    else if (size_arg == 2) binary_cond = 0x8000;
    else binary_cond = 0x8000000;

    if (*ptr & binary_cond)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bit_num * size_arg; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", (*ptr & binary_cond) ? '1' : '0');
            *ptr <<= 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else printf("First byte is zero\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
    char fifth;
    fifth = 0b10100110;

    int size_arg = sizeof(fifth);
    printf("%d\n", size_arg);

    checkFirstBit(size_arg, fifth);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что работать с переменным количеством аргументов через указатели нельзя, как и возвращать 0 из `void`-функции...

Comment: Первый (правый) бит можно проверить побитовым "и" (`&`). `1 & 1 // -> 1`, `0b0100 & 1 // -> 0`. Правда не знаю, возможно ли это в C, хотя уверен на 99%, что можно.

Comment: @smellyshovel Я так понимаю, что ТС "первым" именует старший бит.

Comment: @Harry. Возможно. Но я комментарий не буду удалять, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится в качестве наводки.

Comment: Можно получить маску простым сдвигом типа `1 << (size_arg-1)*8+7`...

Comment: запись проще - `1<<(size_arg*8-1)`

Comment: @DmitryK , Harry  <pre> 1 << (size_arg-1)*8+7  </pre> & <pre> - 1<<(size_arg*8-1) </pre> понял спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте решим более корректно поставленную задачу: определение, установлен ли старший бит в массиве из `N` байт по адресу `ptr`.

Здесь, если мы рассматриваем эти байты как представление числа, нам нужно различать little endian и big endian. На всякий пожарный :)

Так что я бы делал так:

```
#define IS_BIG_ENDIAN (!*(unsigned char *)&(uint16_t){1})

int msb_1(void * ptr, unsigned int n)
{
    if (IS_BIG_ENDIAN) return (*(unsigned char *)ptr & 0x80) != 0;
    return (*((unsigned char *)ptr + n-1) & 0x80) != 0;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 0b10100110;
    unsigned char b = 0b00100110;

    int c = -7;
    int d = 7;

    printf("%d\n", msb_1(&a,1));
    printf("%d\n", msb_1(&b,1));

    printf("%d\n", msb_1(&c,sizeof(c)));
    printf("%d\n", msb_1(&d,sizeof(d)));

}
```

Comment: спасибо, но у меня конечно смешанные чувства я не обладаю еще знаниями для этого кода,
 не могли бы вы объяснить конструкцию "(!*(unsigned char *)&(uint16_t){1})" я ее не понимаю, (занимаюсь Си  дней 7) 
так же не понимаю (unsigned char *)ptr + n-1)  почему  "+n-1"

Comment: Ну, первую конструкцию можете пока считать магией :) Или просто нулем, исходя из того, что у вас обычный компьютер типа PC, такчто в функции `msb_1` остается только одна строчка с `return`. А вторая — потому что первым в памяти при little endian идет самый младший байт, а нам нужен самый старший. Вот мы и перемещаем указатель так, чтобы указывал на старший байт. Например, если размер `int` — 4 байта, то `ptr` указывает на самый младший, "первый справа" (назовем это так) байт. Чтобы указывать на четвертый, надо прибавить 3.

Comment: Спасибо! пусть пока некоторые вещи останутся магией.